# Can I bring a cat with FIV into Argentina?

Tags: argentina, pets

I am planning to move to Argentina (from the United States) in the next year. There is a cat I am considering adopting that is FIV positive. While doing some research to see if her condition would prevent me from taking her with me to Argentina, I came across this site: https://www.pettravel.com/immigration/argentina.cfm. It says “veterinary officials will inspect your animal upon landing” and “if your dog or cat is not in apparent good health, further examination at your expense...”. This isn’t clear to me about FIV, and it’s not an official source. Does anyone know about bringing an FIV positive cat into Argentina?

- [Feline immunodeficiency virus (FIV)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feline_immunodeficiency_virus)

Comment: This is probably better answered on https://pets.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why this cat? Why now? If you're planning to emigrate why not adopt a cat once you've moved? It'll avoid all the issues associated with veterinary inspections, shipping an animal, possible quarantine requirements...

Comment: My understanding is that FIV positive cats should be given a low stress life style. Long distance travel and relocation seems to be stressful for pets. I would try to find an adopter in the local area for this cat.